# nestjs multer and raw body

Tags: nestjs, multer

i have a nestjs web application where i need to support a post endpoint that allows users to upload file to a system we integrate with.

this works with multiform-partdata - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

alternatively the raw Body - https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/raw-body
also works with fastify

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
  AppModule,
  new FastifyAdapter(),
  {
    rawBody: true,
  },
);
```

```
 @Post()
  create(@Req() req: RawBodyRequest<FastifyRequest>) {
    const raw = req.rawBody; // returns a `Buffer`.
  }
```

is there some way we can make both these approaches work in a single nestjs application?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "both these approaches"? Both multer and fastify, or both multer and raw-body using express as the underlying HTTP adapter?

Comment: i would like to use both multer and fastify in the same application(nestjs). Is that even possible.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload 



WARNING
Multer cannot process data which is not in the supported multipart format (multipart/form-data). Also, note that this package is not compatible with the FastifyAdapter.


Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nest's `FileInterceptor` from `@nestjs/platform-express` is **not** compatibel with fastify, **but** all is not lost as there's a package that brings feature parity to express with fastify. [`@nest-labs/fastify-multer`](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-lab/tree/main/packages/fastify-multer). Essentially the same API as the interceptor from `@nestjs/platform-express`, but you have to ensure to import the `FastifyMulterModule` so that the content-parser for `multipart/form-data` is registered with fastify. [I have a worked example that you can view here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/gazer/tree/3e58cb699573bb1cac82717851868f9c8da4ac1e/libs/server/image/src/lib)